# How to use Docusign C# SDK without the webapp?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the C# sdk for Docusign. My original plan is to make it receive POST data from another webapp, and from there, it will automatically send emails to the signers (akin to Remote Signing).

My question is, is there a way to do remote signing without having to run the webapp, go to the webapp url, and clicking the Remote signing option?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can, but then you won't be using remote signing.
You could use embedded signing and generate your own URLs.
Your server would get the information needed (presumably the **envelopeID** at least) and then on the fly generate an embedded signing and show it to the user in your own app.
This is not recommended, mostly because DocuSign is doing a lot on the email front, to ensure no spam/phishing issues etc. But you can do it if you wanted to for some reason.

Comment: I decided to just use the C# sdk webapp embedded signing, receive data from my other webapp, and then just change the code to send an email to the other signer (I have two signers, the first will have to visit the docusign webapp). 

Do you think this is the better way to do things?

Comment: it's an option, if that works for you. Any questions/issues?